# Submitting forms via Turbolinks 5 while also invoking preventDefault - breaks back button behavior on Chrome for iOS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, preventdefault, turbolinks

I have noticed an issue on Chrome for iOS where if I try to handle form submission by first invoking jQuery's preventDefault and then submitting via Turbolinks 5 (Turbolinks.visit), the back button functionality seems broken.  e.g. if I do a few searches, then hit the back button, I am returned all the way back to the page that I was on before visiting my domain.

Hopefully it's not because I don't understand something basic about preventDefault().  The reason I have to invoke preventDefault is that asynchronous code like the geolocation success callback will not be blocked on by the browser and I want the callback to modify the form (see example code below).  Is preventDefault() somehow stopping the window.history API invocations made by Turbolinks 5?

I generated this app through `rails new` with alterations pasted below. Specs: Rails 4.2.7, Turbolinks 5.0.1.  I am using this software on my iPhone 6: iOS 9.3.5, Chrome for iOS 53.0.2785.86.

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to random site e.g. nytimes.com
- Go to localhost:3000
- Type "restaurant" in for place category input and tap search
- Type "bar" in for place category input and tap search
- Check back behavior: - should see your "restaurant" search, then should see root page, then should see nytimes.com.  On mobile Safari this works, but on Chrome for iOS the first back button tap goes straight to nytimes.com

A copy of this application: https://github.com/rohitgupta3/turbolinks-chromeios

config/routes.rb

```
root 'page#home'
```

app/controllers/page_controller.rb

```
def home; end
```

app/views/page/home.html.erb

```
<div>Most recent search:</div>
<div><%= params[:place_category] %></div>
<div><%= params[:user_lat] %></div>
<div><%= params[:user_lng] %></div>

<hr>

<%= form_tag(root_path, id: 'search-form' ) do %>
  <%= label_tag :place_category, 'Place category' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :place_category %>
  <br><br>
  Don't fill in below inputs (geolocation JavaScript will do it for you)
  <br>
  <%= text_field_tag :user_lat %>
  <%= text_field_tag :user_lng %>
  <br><br><br>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

app/assets/javascripts/search_form.js (included via default `require_tree .`)

```
// Note: if you remove preventDefault() and it seems to be working
// perfectly, just use geoSuccessWait instead of geoSuccess (geoSuccess
// may be called fast enough to beat the browser's default submit)

$(document).on('submit', '#search-form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  function geoSuccess(position) {
    $('input[name="user_lat"]').val(position.coords.latitude);
    $('input[name="user_lng"]').val(position.coords.longitude);
    var $searchForm = $(e.target);
    Turbolinks.visit($searchForm.attr('action') + "?" + $searchForm.serialize());
  }
  // function geoSuccessWait(position) { setTimeout(function() {geoSuccess(position); }, 1000) }
  var geoOptions = { maximumAge: 10000, timeout: 5000 };
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    geoSuccess, // or geoSuccessWait for a longer lag
    function(error) { },
    geoOptions
  );
});
```

Comment: This is a common thing which I have noticed in my application, where I have a page for approving or rejecting threads using ajax. Once I have approved/rejected certain no. of items and then if I go to next page and come back to the approvals page again using browser back functionality, all the items are untouched as if I have not taken any action on them. I use Rails 3 without turbolinks.

Comment: Now same thing happened in Stackoverflow also, I made this comment closed the tab, and then opened it again using cmd+shift+t( ctrl_shft+t in windows) and the comment which I made was not there. I had to refresh the page to see my comment. I guess its browser's behaviour.

Comment: Your first comment seem to talk about caching on back/forward navigation, which is not what I'm asking about.  I'm not even sure how your second comment is possible given cmd+shift+t should refresh the page and therefore you should see the comment.  I'm asking about the browser's history stack not having entries when it should.